# Opening a modal in Filament PHP

Tags: php, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I'm using `filament-php` framework, and in my Resource page, in a given form, after download is finished, I would like to open a modal. But thus far, I have failed to do so. There is a method `afterStateUpdated` that I can hook into, with `Livewire` compnent, which should open it up, but it just does not. Documentation: https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/support/blade-components/modal#controlling-a-modal-from-javascript

The modal is in the `app.blade.php` template listed as

```html
<x-filament::modal id="loading" icon="heroicon-o-exclamation-triangle" icon-color="danger">
    <x-filament::loading-indicator class="h-5 w-5" />
</x-filament::modal>
```

In the upload form on the `Resource` page, I do

```php
    public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Wizard::make([
                    Wizard\Step::make('Import from PDF (AI)')
                        ->schema([
                            FileUpload::make('attachment')
                                ->storeFiles(false)
                                ->afterStateUpdated(function (
                                    TemporaryUploadedFile $state,
                                    \Livewire\Component $livewire
                                ) {
                                    $livewire->dispatch('open-modal', 'loading');
                                })
                                ->live()
                        ]),
```

Technically this should looking at the docs fire and open up the modal action with loading. But thus far, I have not been able to make it work.

Would anybody here have experience with `filament` and how to approach this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Using **Filament**:

## Modal from Action button:

```
->schema([
    Forms\Components\TextInput::make('actionButton') 
    \Filament\Forms\Components\Actions::make([
        \Filament\Forms\Components\Actions\Action::make('customAction')
            ->label('Delete action')
            ->requiresConfirmation()
            ->modalIcon('heroicon-o-trash')
            ->modalIconColor('warning')
            ->modalDescription('Are you sure you\'d like to delete this post? This cannot be undone.')
            ->modalSubmitActionLabel('Yes, delete it')
            ->action(function () {
                dd('custom action');
            })
    ])
]),
```

More options: https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/actions/prebuilt-actions/create

## Modal from event:

On PHP:

```
...
->afterStateUpdated(function (){
  $this->dispatch('open-modal', id: 'edit-user');
)},
...

protected function getForms(): array
    {   
        return [
            'form' => $this->form(
                    ...
                ),
            ),
            'getUserModal' => $this->form(
                $this->makeForm()
                    ->schema([                    
                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name'),
                        Forms\Components\Actions::make([
                            Forms\Components\Actions\Action::make('closeUserModal')
                            ->label('Close')
                            ->color('secondary') 
                            ->extraAttributes([
                                'x-on:click' => 'isOpen = false'  // close modal [FASTER]
                            ]),
                            // OR
                            // ->action(function () {
                            //     $this->dispatch('close-modal', id: 'edit-user'); // close modal
                            // }),
                            Forms\Components\Actions\Action::make('saveUserModal')
                            ->label('Save')
                            ->color('primary')         
                            ->action(function (Get $get) {
                                logger($get('name'));
                            }),
                        ])->fullWidth(),
                    ]),
            ),
        ];
    }
```

On template:

```
<x-filament::modal id="edit-user" :close-by-clicking-away="false">
  {{ $this->getUserModal }}
</x-filament::modal>
```

If you use **Jetstream**:
On PHP:

```
public $showModal = false;
...
->afterStateUpdated(function (){
  $this->showModal = true;
)},

public function confirmingUserDeletion(){
    dd('confirmingUserDeletion');
}
public function deleteUser(){
    dd('deleteUser');
}
```

On template:

```
<x-confirmation-modal wire:model="showModal">
    <x-slot name="title">
        Delete Account
    </x-slot>

    <x-slot name="content">
        Are you sure you want to delete your account? Once your account is deleted, all data will be permanently deleted.
    </x-slot>

    <x-slot name="footer">
        <x-secondary-button wire:click="$toggle('confirmingUserDeletion')" wire:loading.attr="disabled">
            Nevermind
        </x-secondary-button>

        <x-danger-button class="ml-2" wire:click="deleteUser" wire:loading.attr="disabled">
            Delete Account
        </x-danger-button>
    </x-slot>
</x-confirmation-modal>
```